# how to filter csv to keep rows with the first column ending in +

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I'm trying to filter a CSV file by the first column. In particular, I have countries and continents where the continent names end with '+' signs. For example, I may have column elements 'Africa +', 'Ryu', 'Europe +', and 'Blanka' in column 1.

So far, I've tried to do `awk -F ',' '$1 ~ /\+/' boomboom.csv > test.txt`
 to no avail. This works but I want to only filter on names that END with a +, not names that have a +.

Any ideas?

FYI, the boomboom.csv file looks like this

```
...
"Africa +","51","KO","1964","pounds","84","A "
"Africa +","51","KO","1963","pounds","73","O "
"Africa +","51","KO","1962","kg","726","B "
"Ryu","31","Regulation","2000","pounds","40","A "
"Ryu","31","Regulation","2001","pounds","380","B "
...
```

Comment: Have you checked the man page and tried to find out the meaning of `-F`? If not, try that first.

Comment: Failing hek2mgl's advice, try using a csv parser.

Comment: If you had the right syntax, your script would print the ones with a plus in the first field.  Is that what you want?  Or remove the ones with a plus?

Comment: when I asked a question, sometimes man comments, "what have you tried", ok, I just paste something text containing "awk" to show that i tried."  You do tried, except for the `awk`, no part in your short command is correct. If you don't know awk syntax at all, at least do some google...

Comment: Your question is not clear. Show an example input file and the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux, `awk` is usually provided by `gawk`, and the matching statement `$1 ~ /\+/` you are using is called a *regular expression*.

In the future, you might refer to the [documentation for gawk regular expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp.html)

A fairly close match for your problem would be:

```
gawk -F ',' '$1 ~ /\+"?$/'
```

The regex `\+"?$` breaks down as follows:

`\+` requires a `+` .  The `\` escapes the `+` to mean a literal `+` character as `+` otherwise has a special meaning in a regular expression as requiring "1 or more of" whatever preceded it

`"?` says that after the `+` there may or may not be a `"` because the `?` character has a special meaning in a regular expression as requiring "0 or 1 of" whatever preceded it

`$` says that after that the `+` and possible `"`, the string ends

This regex will print variations such as:

```
 "apricot+",..
  apricot+,...
 "apricot"+,...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, however here is something to think about.

If you only want the continents the essence of your awk statement is:

```
awk '{if($1 ~ /\+/) print;}'
```

If you only want countries then:

```
awk '{if($1 !~ /\+/) print;}'
```

Comment: There's no need to use `if`s and `print`s here. These are equivalent to `awk '$1 ~ /\+/'` and `awk '$1 !~ /\+/'`.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the shorter version @Filipe. I have a habit of being verbose....